# Adjust environments's behaviour when nested

Tags: spacing, environments, nesting

I would like to define an environment which behaves differently when it is nested.  This environment should ignore spaces at the begin and end of the environment.  I have this working as I desire when it is not nested. But, when it is nested I can't seem to get the desired behavior.

The first box here is the desired behavior using a non nested version.  I would like the second nested version of this environment to behave as if it were not nested.  However, there are two issues with the current implementation:

1. I am required to add a trailing `%` to `\begin{MyBoxedEnvironment}%` when nested.  Otherwise I end up with an extra line in between. (See **`1`** in the MWE).
2. I can not have a blank line following the start of this environment when nested. This can be fixed by manually adding a `\par\noindent` but would prefer not to have to do that.
   (See **`2`** in the MWE).

[image]

As you can see below, I use a counter to count the depth of the nesting, and only `\begin`,`\end` the `mdframed` environment when the counter is zero.
If there is a better way to detect that an environment is nested that would be useful as well.

### Code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{mdframed}

\newcommand*{\Text}{%
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. 
    Sed accumsan nulla ac ipsum elementum interdum. 
    Praesent ultricies faucibus turpis, non scelerisque nisi bibendum et.
}%

\newmdenv[%
    backgroundcolor=yellow!10,%
    linewidth=2pt,%
    skipabove=0pt,%
    skipbelow=0pt,%
    ]{MyBoxedEnvironmentMdframed}%

\newcounter{MyBoxEnvironmentDepth}%
\setcounter{MyBoxEnvironmentDepth}{0}% just to be clear we start at 0

\newenvironment{MyBoxedEnvironment}{%
    \ignorespaces%
    \par\noindent%
    \ifnum\value{MyBoxEnvironmentDepth}>0%
        % Ignore begin environment since it is nested.
    \else%
        \begin{MyBoxedEnvironmentMdframed}%
    \fi%
    \addtocounter{MyBoxEnvironmentDepth}{1}% increment depth
}{%
    \addtocounter{MyBoxEnvironmentDepth}{-1}% decrement depth
    \ifnum\value{MyBoxEnvironmentDepth}>0%
        % Ignore end environment since it is nested.
    \else%
        \end{MyBoxedEnvironmentMdframed}%
    \fi%
    \ignorespacesafterend%
}%

\begin{document}
\begin{MyBoxedEnvironment}

    \Text

    \par\noindent
    \textcolor{red}{\Text}

\end{MyBoxedEnvironment}

\begin{MyBoxedEnvironment}

    \Text

    \begin{MyBoxedEnvironment} % 1. Why space here matter?

        % 2. Why does blank line above yield extra line
        %\par\noindent% Don't want to have to add this
        \textcolor{red}{\Text}
    \end{MyBoxedEnvironment}
\end{MyBoxedEnvironment}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It seems you don't really need the counter just a switch If you define \foo to do `\begin{MyBoxedEnvironmentMdframed}` then your environment can call `\foo\let\foo\relax` and same for the end environment then in nested cases `\foo` will do nothing without needing a counter or explicit test.

updated example as requested

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{mdframed}

\newcommand*{\Text}{%
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. 
    Sed accumsan nulla ac ipsum elementum interdum. 
    Praesent ultricies faucibus turpis, non scelerisque nisi bibendum et.%
}

\newmdenv[
    backgroundcolor=yellow!10,
    linewidth=2pt,
    skipabove=0pt,
    skipbelow=0pt,
    ]{MyBoxedEnvironmentMdframed}


\newenvironment{MyBoxedEnvironment}{%
    \def\MyBoxedEnvironment{%
    \let\endMyBoxedEnvironment\empty
    \par\noindent\ignorespaces}
    \begin{MyBoxedEnvironmentMdframed}%
    \par\noindent\ignorespaces
}{%
    \end{MyBoxedEnvironmentMdframed}%
    \ignorespacesafterend
}




\begin{document}
\begin{MyBoxedEnvironment}
\Text
\par\noindent
\textcolor{red}{\Text}
\end{MyBoxedEnvironment}

\begin{MyBoxedEnvironment}
\Text
\begin{MyBoxedEnvironment}
\textcolor{red}{\Text}
\end{MyBoxedEnvironment}
\end{MyBoxedEnvironment}
\end{document}
```

Edit: additional comments (which are apparently too long for the comment system)

Using `\relax` here is probably safe enough but it puts an unexpandable token into the stream whereas a space/newline does not, so it is not always safe to do that. `\ignorespaces` only ignores space tokens following it so if you follow it with some non-expandable token as in your MWE it does nothing. Similarly after you have done a `\par`  blank lines will have no effect at all. Unless you are sure you only ever want text it's not normally a good idea to start with `\noindent` as that actually starts the paragraph, so nested display material would be incorrectly set. Better to set `\parindent` to zero if you just want non-indented paragraphs.

Comment: I am not sure I full understand this. I see that there is no problem with what you propose related to the `\begin{}`, but not how it would work with the `\end{}`? If I redefine the end environment how will I know when it ends?

Comment: I'll edit some code into my answer, would probably have modified it originally but my TL2010 install gives `! Undefined control sequence.
l.11 \newmdenv` on your MWE and it;s midnight:-)

Comment: Had to update both etoolbox and mdframed from tl2010 version to run the example, but updated as requested (taking @egreg's version as base)

Comment: Wow!! I see that it works, but ...how? Can you add something about why the outermost `\end{MyBoxedEnvironment}` still works. Get some sleep first though... Is it a grouping effect? The revised definition of `\MyBoxedEnvironment` is only within the outer environment so the redefinition is only applied to the inner environments?

Comment: More or less, yes. night:-)

Answer (score 8):

Two errors: the `\ignorespaces` must go last, after `\par\noindent`; the indentation in the nested environment is of course caused by the blank line after `\begin{MyBoxedEnvironment}`.

Here's a corrected version with properly placed `%` characters (for example, after `0` in the `\ifnum` lines there should *not* be a `%`).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{mdframed}

\newcommand*{\Text}{%
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. 
    Sed accumsan nulla ac ipsum elementum interdum. 
    Praesent ultricies faucibus turpis, non scelerisque nisi bibendum et.%
}

\newmdenv[
    backgroundcolor=yellow!10,
    linewidth=2pt,
    skipabove=0pt,
    skipbelow=0pt,
    ]{MyBoxedEnvironmentMdframed}

\newcounter{MyBoxEnvironmentDepth}
\setcounter{MyBoxEnvironmentDepth}{0}% just to be clear we start at 0

\newenvironment{MyBoxedEnvironment}{%
    \ifnum\value{MyBoxEnvironmentDepth}>0
        % Ignore begin environment since it is nested.
    \else
        \begin{MyBoxedEnvironmentMdframed}%
    \fi
    \addtocounter{MyBoxEnvironmentDepth}{1}% increment depth
    \par\noindent\ignorespaces
}{%
    \addtocounter{MyBoxEnvironmentDepth}{-1}% decrement depth
    \ifnum\value{MyBoxEnvironmentDepth}>0
        % Ignore end environment since it is nested.
    \else
        \end{MyBoxedEnvironmentMdframed}%
    \fi
    \ignorespacesafterend
}

\begin{document}
\begin{MyBoxedEnvironment}
\Text
\par\noindent
\textcolor{red}{\Text}
\end{MyBoxedEnvironment}

\begin{MyBoxedEnvironment}
\Text
\begin{MyBoxedEnvironment}
\textcolor{red}{\Text}
\end{MyBoxedEnvironment}
\end{MyBoxedEnvironment}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I prefer `%` at end of lines in the preamble so I changed the ones that end with a number to `\relax%` then things should be fine? I would prefer that blank lines at the begin of the environment to not result in an indent so that was why I had tried to put the `\ignorespaces`?

Comment: A blank line can't be intercepted by `\ignorespaces`, that comes into action after the tokenization, when the empty line has been already converted into `\par`. You'd need a slower routine that ignores both spaces and `\par` tokens.

Answer (score 4):

I am not sure whether `\ignorespaces` here will do anything useful; try putting it at the very end of the definition of `\begin{...}` (here, after the counter increment).  Also, why not include `\par\noindent` in the definition of your encironment, right before `\ignorespaces`?  (Please excuse if I'm talking rubbish; it's 00:50 am here, and I'm looking at TeX.SE to rest after a hard day;).)

Also, *never* put percent signs after numerical constants!!!  They should be followed by a space or newline, and if you don't obey that rule, someday a nasty, stupid bug will eat you!

Comment: As far as the numerical constants, I normally end them with `\relax%`, but missed it this time.

Comment: +1 for "*never* put percent signs after numerical constants"