# Extra space above `amsmath` environment inside `mdframed`

Tags: math-mode, spacing, amsmath, mdframed

When I use this code some space above appears.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{mdframed}

\begin{document}

\begin{mdframed}    
\begin{gather*}
    \lambda^2-2\lambda = 0\\
    \lambda_1 = 0, \enspace \lambda_2 = 2
\end{gather*}
\end{mdframed}

\end{document}
```

[image]

I tried to implement [this answer by egreg](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/36963) and it works, however I am getting these errors.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{mdframed}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\makeatletter
\pretocmd\start@gather{%
    \if@mdframed\kern-\topskip\kern-\abovedisplayskip\fi
}{}{}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{mdframed}    
\begin{gather*}
    \lambda^2-2\lambda = 0\\
    \lambda_1 = 0, \enspace \lambda_2 = 2
\end{gather*}
\end{mdframed}

\end{document}
```

[image]

---

Also I would like to know how to make it work for all the `amsmath` envinronments. Now only one with `\start@gather` is affected.

Comment: This problem is addressed by this question: [Spurious space above `align` environment at top of page/`minipage`](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/36954)

Comment: Yes, I know, but as I said, I implemented this to my case i.e. I've changed `\start@align` to `\start@gather` and `\if@minipage` to `\if@mdframed`

Comment: \if@mdframed doesn't exist.

Comment: Related Question: [Excess vertical space in mdframed ending with display math environment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/44131/4301).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As @UlrikeFischer pointed in the question comment, there is no boolean `\if@mdframed` in `mdframed` package. The following workaround

- uses the value of TeX count `\mdf@envdepth` to determine if the code is executed inside `mdframed` environtment, and
- patches each of `\start@gather`, `\start@align` and `\start@multline`.

Hope that would work for every `amsmath` multiline displayed equation environment.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{mdframed}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\makeatletter
\pretocmd\start@gather{%
  \ifnum\mdf@envdepth>0
    \kern\glueexpr-\topskip-\abovedisplayskip\relax
  \fi
}{}{\fail}
\pretocmd\start@align{%
  \ifnum\mdf@envdepth>0
    \kern\glueexpr-\topskip-\abovedisplayskip\relax
  \fi
}{}{\fail}
\pretocmd\start@multline{%
  \ifnum\mdf@envdepth>0
    \kern\glueexpr-\topskip-\abovedisplayskip\relax
  \fi
}{}{\fail}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

gather:
\begin{mdframed}    
\begin{gather*}
    \lambda^2-2\lambda = 0\\
    \lambda_1 = 0, \enspace \lambda_2 = 2
\end{gather*}
\end{mdframed}

align:
\begin{mdframed}    
\begin{align*}
    \lambda^2-2\lambda = 0\\
    \lambda_1 = 0, \enspace \lambda_2 = 2
\end{align*}
\end{mdframed}

multline:
\begin{mdframed}    
\begin{multline*}
    \lambda^2-2\lambda = 0\\
    \lambda_1 = 0, \enspace \lambda_2 = 2
\end{multline*}
\end{mdframed}

\end{document}
```

[image]

---

A looping version in case you prefer a more compact patching code:

```
\makeatletter
\@for\@tempa:=gather,align,multline\do{%
  \expandafter\pretocmd\csname start@\@tempa\endcsname{%
    \ifnum\mdf@envdepth>0
      \kern\glueexpr-\topskip-\abovedisplayskip\relax
    \fi
  }{}{\fail}
}
\makeatother
```

Here `\@for` is a LaTeX2e internal macro which is documented in, for example [`macros2e`](http://mirrors.ctan.org/info/macros2e/macros2e.pdf) documentation.

Comment: Perfect! Special thanks for the compact version..

Comment: @antshar My original answer was wrong. See my updated answer for an improved solution.

Comment: What was wrong with the previous version?

Comment: @antshar Hmmm, that's strange. I thought the old solution will cause problems but it did not. Rollbacked to the old solution.

Comment: @antshar It seems the `\kern` added before envs like `align` which is not at the very beginning of `mdframed` inserts a horizontal skip (10pt), not vertical, but that skip is not shown. Maybe because of the centering alignment of equation? Not sure.