# Is there a way of defining a command which is automatically converted to a no-op after its first execution?

Tags: macros, expansion

**Is there a way of defining a command that can be executed only once and is then redefined to be a no-op?**

Related:

- [Is there a way of defining a command \nullifyifmoved{arg} that will normally act like its argument but act like a no-op if the macro is “moved”?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/99657/14996)
- [Macro to be used in a \section command that has no effect in the table of contents](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/99473/14996)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

An easy way is to just nullify the macro within the body so that the next time it does not have an effect if it is called again via either

```
\global\let\FirstTime\relax%
```

or

```
\global\def\FirstTime{}%
```

[image]

As per David Carlisle's comment, we need to add a `\global` to ensure that the macro is nullified for subsequent use in the case the first use was within a group (as per updated test case below)

### References:

- A similar thing can be done for environments. For instance in [Adjust environments's behaviour when nested](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/43765/adjust-environmentss-behaviour-when-nested), I wanted to disable the environment if it was ever nested.
- [What is the difference between \relax and {}?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/86385/what-is-the-difference-between-relax-and/)

### Code:

```
\documentclass{article}

\newcommand*{\FirstTime}{%
    \gdef\FirstTime{}%
    \textbf{FirstTime: }%
}%


\begin{document}
\begingroup
    abcd \FirstTime defg \FirstTime xys
\endgroup

    abcd \FirstTime defg \FirstTime xys

    abcd \FirstTime defg \FirstTime xys
\end{document}
```

Comment: Credit also goes to user "Stephen" who posted [a similar answer to an earlier question of mine](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/99494/14996).